# How to choose a continent by the country?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2 and mongoid 7.0

I need to choose a continent by the country

I understand that it should look something like this:

```
class Place
  field :country, type: String
  field :continent, type: String

  after_save :update_continent

  def update_continent
    cont = self.country

    case cont
    when 'United States', 'Grenada'
      'NA'
    when 'Netherlands', 'Spain'
      'EU'
    end

    self.continent = cont
  end

 end
```

Comment: @jvillian I want to know I'm moving in the right direction or not

Comment: You are moving in *a* direction. Whether or not it is the *right* direction is difficult to say. There is more than one way to accomplish what you are trying to do. What makes one approach "right" as compared to another? This code looks quite close. So, perhaps yes, you are moving in the right direction. Except, apparently, you have 'New York' and 'Chicago' stored as countries. But, that's more of a semantic problem than a syntactic one.

Comment: You haven't told us whether your code works and if not what it does, or what errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you indicated you are using Mongoid:

1. Each Mongoid model class must `include Mongoid::Document`, per the documentation in https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/.
2. `after_save` callbacks are normally used for things like creating external jobs, not for setting attributes, because the attribute changes won't be persisted (as the model was already saved). Usually attribute changes are done in `before_validation` or `before_save` callbacks. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html for the list of available callbacks.
3. As pointed out by Toby, the case statement is not correctly used. Its result should be assigned like this:

.

```
def update_continent
  self.continent = case self.country
  when 'United States', 'Grenada'
    'NA'
  when 'Netherlands', 'Spain'
    'EU'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help), I forgot that `after_save` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough context to be able to answer your question, but since you just want to be pointed in the right direction, and since you seem to be new here I'm happy to give you some pointers.

1. You're class uses the `after_save` method as if it is an ActiveRecord Model, but without extending or including anything it's just a Plain Old Ruby Object. To make the `after_save` callback work you need to at least extend `ActiveModel::Callbacks` but probably you want to make it a full ActiveRecord Model. To do that in Rails 4 you subclass `ActiveRecord::Base` and in rails 6 you subclass `ApplicationRecord` But I don't actually know how it's done in Rails 5.
2. If you have a normal database in the back end as is usual for rails you don't need to declare the fields, it automatically gets them from the equivalent table in the database (though perhaps this is not true when using Mongoid. I don't know). if you run this command in your terminal in your app base directory: `rails generate model Place country:string continent:string` it will create the migration file needed to make the database table and the Model file (with whatever the correct superclass is) and you wont need to do all the boilerplate stuff yourself.
3. You have a variable named `cont` and you assign a country to it. This will get very confusing given that you also have a separate concept of "continent" Better to not abbreviate your variable names and choose sensible naming.
4. You're not using the case statement correctly. The output of the statement doesn't automatically get assigned to the the variable you're switching on. You need to read up on Ruby syntax.
5. Overall I suspect in the long run you would do well to have separate models for Continent and Country. With a Continent having many countries and a country belonging to a continent. Rails is a framework that makes that sort of thing very easy to do and manage. You probably need to read some more and look at examples and videos about the basics of Ruby on Rails.

I highly recommend [The Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) by Hartl. It's free online. Working through that or an equivalent should give you a much better understanding of how Rails is equipped to handle your situation and how to best utilise it to get the outcome you need. This was indispensable for me when I was first starting out with Rails.